# Merge all dataframe from list which contain common columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of data frame :

```
dfList= [df1,df2]

shape of df1 (100,3)
shape of df2 (100,3)

df1

a  b  c
1  2  4
1  2  3
1  2  6  
1  3  9

df2 

a  b  d
1  2  9
1  2  11
1  2  6  
1  3  3
```

I want to merge or concat all the dataframe in the list to get the below final dataframe:

```
df_final
a  b  c  d
1  2  4  9
1  2  3  11
1  2  6  6  
1  3  9  3
```

I am trying the below code:

```
df_final = pd.merge(left=dfList[0], right=dfList[1], how='inner')
```

But I want to handle the case where If I have more than 2 dataframe in the list like `dfList=[df1,df2,df3,df4]`.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: are the common columns same for all the dataframes? In your example df1 and df2 columns a,b are common. So can we say a,b will be common to all the dataframes?

Comment: @crappyprog - yes absolutely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I think it would be easier to use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and then just drop the duplicate columns:

```
df_final = pd.concat(dfList,axis=1).reset_index(drop=True).T.drop_duplicates().T
```

**Example based on the input data given**:

```
dfList = [df1,df2]
df_final = pd.concat(dfList,axis=1).reset_index(drop=True).T.drop_duplicates().T
print(df_final)
```

**Output**:

```
   a  b  c   d
0  1  2  4   9
1  1  2  3  11
2  1  2  6   6
3  1  3  9   3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:
assume you have 3 df as below

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

df1 = pd.read_table('set1.csv', sep=<delimiter>)
df2 = pd.read_table('set2.csv', sep=<delimiter>)
df3 = pd.read_table('set3.csv', sep=<delimiter>)
```

The source of your dataframes could of course be different.

Create a list of dataframes

```
df = [df1, df2, df3]
```

and merge them

```
df_full = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=<variable to merge on>,
                                            how='inner'), df).fillna('void')
```

the last entry `fillna('void')`

Comment: In my case, there is no keys. All columns are common except one column in each dataframe. I want to eliminate the parameter `on`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do then is:
`pdList = [df1, df2, ...]`  to create list of df you want to concatenate and

```
new_df = pd.concat(pdList)
```

Then drop duplicate columns:

```
df = new_df .loc[:,~new_df .columns.duplicated()]
```

Comment: I tried your solution , but in this case my dataframe shape would become (200,3), I want dataframe shape to be (100,3)